# What FSTs (File System Translators) exist for the Apple IIGS?

Tags: data-transfer, apple-iigs, hfs

Apple supplied some, were there others that other people wrote? What is the complete list of FSTs available?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The official ones, with GS/OS versions as indicated by the [Apple II History site](http://apple2history.org/history/ah15/):

```
Filename        Purpose                                 In GS/OS Version
APPLESHARE.FST  For AppleTalk networks                  5.0
CHAR.FST        Keyboard, screen, printers, and modems  4.0
DOS3.3.FST      Apple II DOS 3.3 Disks (Read only)      6.0
HFS.FST         Mac OS HFS Disks (Read/Write)           6.0
HS.FST          High Sierra CD-ROMs                     4.0
MSDOS.FST       MS-DOS Disks (Read only)                6.0.1
PASCAL.FST      Apple II Pascal Disks (Read only)       6.0
PRO.FST         Apple II ProDOS Disks (Read/Write)      4.0
```

Apple didn't release documentation on writing FSTs, perhaps because they often involved changes to GS/OS internals. This is discussed at the Apple II History link above.

However, the following unofficial ones were developed by [Brutal Deluxe](http://www.brutaldeluxe.fr/products/apple2gs/fsts.html):

```
DOS3.2.FST      Apple II DOS 3.2 Disks
DOS3.3.FST      Apple II DOS 3.3 Disks (Improved)
RDOS3.3.FST     Apple II RDOS Disks (SSI games)
```

Comment: Semi-related: the HFS FST in System 6.0.1 had a somewhat serious bug: http://macgui.com/downloads/?file_id=11654

Comment: Thanks. A few bugs including that one were [fixed in 6.0.2](http://a2central.com/6412/apple-iigs-system-software-6-0-2/).

Comment: With the GUPP patch HFS is stable under GSOS, and offers some significant advantages for hard disk partitions. HFS supports up to 2 GB partitions where ProDOS partitions are limited to 32 MB and HFS directory IO is generally faster than ProDOS for larger disks.